# VS2010 does not display "Team" in Menu

Tags: tfs

I am using 2012 for connecting to TFS, but one of my project is in VS2010, when i install the TFS for 2010 version then error message is display "Already installed updated version".

Could any one help me please me on this? How can i connect TFS with VS2010 version?

Answer (score 2):

Your wording is a little confusing, I'm assuming you are saying you want to connect to TFS 2012 using VS 2010.

If so you need to install 2 things on your VS machine:

- [VS 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
- [TFS Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

Then you should be able to choose Connect to TFS (can't remember if that is in the Team or Tools menu).

Comment: It's in the Team menu.

Comment: I think that's incorrect, in VS 2010 I think it was in the Tools menu then moved to Team in VS 2012.